# I want to display 2 smoothed variables from a GAMM on the same graph

Tags: ggplot2, predict, mixed-models, gam, mgcv

x2 will represent factors "a" and "b" for this simplified example, and f3 is the random effect. (I don't know if the compound symmetry correlation is part of my problem).

gamm(response~x2 + s(x1, by=x2) + correlation =corCompSymm(form = ~1|f3))

So I have a GAMM with s(x1, by=x2) and I can see the partial effects graphs for each smooth, ie. s(x1):x2a and s(x1):x2b on separate graphs with plot() or draw(). I want to overlay these smooths on the same graph so they will share a y and x axis.

I've tried using gratia because I know it uses ggplot but I can't figure how to use it in this way. I'm unable to use predict_gam(), predict.gam(), or predict() because I receive errors that it's not possible with a gamm.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: You mean `x2` is a *factor* with **two** levels? There must be a typo in your model as you can have `+ correlation = ...` in a `gamm()`. If you need to do this with gratia, you'll need to predict for a range of values in `x1` repeated for both values of `x2`. I'' try to work up an example as I don't think I have a `fitted_values()` working for `"gamm"` objects yet

Comment: Hello Gavin! You're a GAM celebrity! :)

Yes, I meant x2 is a factor with 2 levels. 
I'm using the correlation =corCompSymm(form = ~1|Plot) in my model because I was directed to do so by a stats professor at my university (Plot is the actual variable I used f3 for earlier). 

I have repeated measures of Plots nested in 2 sample years (my x2 with 2 levels).

Comment: I was originally going to use the partial effects plots in my thesis but my advisor thinks it would look better to have the smoothed functions on the same plot.

Comment: also, I see what you meant with the correlation, I didn't mean to write "+" it's actually a comma in my code.

Comment: OK; I had a busy day so hadn't gotten around to writing an example answer, but I will do it in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

Without doing everything by hand, two options using my {gratia} package spring to mind:

1. evaluate the smooths of `x2` and then plot
2. predict from the model excluding the random effect and the effect of `x0`

The difference between these two is whether you want to include the group means (option 2) or not (option 1).

The  second option in the example below uses new methods for `"gamm"` objects that I have added to {gratia} and that will be in the development version of the package, on GitHub, very shortly. To install this version, follow instruction in the [README](https://gavinsimpson.github.io/gratia/index.html#installing-gratia). The first option works already with the current CRAN version of the apckage.

### Reproducible example

```r
library("mgcv")
library("gratia")
library("ggplot2")

su_re2 <- data_sim("eg4", n = 400,  dist = "normal", scale = 2, seed = 1)
set.seed(42)
su_re2$ranef <- as.factor(sample(1:20, 400, replace = TRUE))
su_re2$X <- model.matrix(~ ranef - 1, data = su_re2)
su_re2 <- transform(su_re2, y = y + X %*% rnorm(20) * 0.5)

rm <- gamm(y ~ fac + s(x2, by = fac) + s(x0), data = su_re2,
    correlation = corCompSymm(form = ~ 1 | ranef))
```

### Evaluate the smooths

The first option is to evaluate the smooths at a regular grid of values along the continuous covariate of interest, for each level of the factor. This reproduces the output from `draw()` (or `mgcv::plot.gam()`), which is to plot the partial effect of the centred smooth. These exclude the group means.

```r
sms <- smooth_estimates(rm, "s(x2)", partial_match = TRUE) |>
  add_confint()

sms |>
  ggplot(aes(x = x2, y = est, colour = fac)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(x = x2, ymin = lower_ci, ymax = upper_ci, fill = fac),
                inherit.aes = FALSE, alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_line()
```

the above produces

[image]

### Predict from the model excluding some terms

The second option is to `predict()` from the model, so that we include the model constant (intercept), the parametric factor terms, and the smooths of `x2`, but exclude the effect of the smooth (`s(x0)`). This will then include the group means.

First, we need to know how {mgcv} names the smooths

```r
sm_names <- smooths(rm)
```

```
> sm_names
[1] "s(x2):fac1" "s(x2):fac2" "s(x2):fac3" "s(x0)"
```

In this instance it is easy as we only need to *exclude* the one simple smooth.

Next, we create a data slice of values to predict at:

- `n = 100` evenly spaced values over the covariate `x2`, and
- the levels of `fac`
- all other variables in the slice will be set to typical values

However, because we are predicting using only the `$gam` component of the model we are excluding the random effect from the predicted/fitted values. Then we pass this to the `fitted_values()` function, and plot

```r
ds <- data_slice(rm, x2 = evenly(x2, n = 100), fac = evenly(fac))
fv <- fitted_values(rm, data = ds, exclude = "s(x0)")

fv |>
  ggplot(aes(x = x2, y = fitted, colour = fac)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(x = x2, ymin = lower, ymax = upper, fill = fac),
                inherit.aes = FALSE, alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_line()
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. 

I was able to run the first example of evaluating the smooths but am having trouble running the second example for the predicted values, which I think is where I'm trying to get to with my analysis.

Comment: I installed the latest gratia like you suggested but perhaps I skipped a step. 
I tried 2 ways and recieved different error messages 
`ds <- data_slice(rm, x2 = evenly(x2, n=100), fac = evenly(fac))` 
Error: `object` does not appear to a `gamm4` model object

`ds <- data_slice(rm$gam, x2 = evenly(x2, n=100), fac = evenly(fac))`
Error in process_slice_var(x = var1, data = mf, n = n) :argument "var1" is missing, with no default

Comment: Nevermind, it took a lot of restarting R for it to work but I got it to work! It only worked when I used `rm$gam` instead of `rm`. Thank you, I'm going to try to apply this to my data now!

Comment: Ah, sorry; I forgot about the `gamm()` bit. I'll look and see if there is a `"gamm"` method and if not add it so this just works without having to call `rm$gam`.

Comment: This is likely a stupid question but I can't seem to get a straight answer-- What is the most appropriate way to visualize your smoothed variables in a paper? I have been using partial effects plots, but it's difficult to explain/interpret the y-axis of partial effect. Is there a next step to using these splines in a more interpretable way? Thank you

Comment: I would be inclined to use counterfactuals when partial plots were not needed; use `data_slice()` to create the counter factual (values of the variable(s) you wish to evaluate the model at), and then use `fitted_values()` to generate predictions from the model for that counter factual, in a form you can visualise with ggplot.

Comment: You can set the other variables you are not varying to appropriate values (in the data_slice call) or have them set to representative values automatically, and you can exclude certain variables (more precisely, certain terms) from the predictions using arguments ´exclude` and `terms. Feel free to email me if you want more guidance, or ask in the Discussion section of the gratia GitHub repo; https://github.com/gavinsimpson/gratia/discussions